# How to create Github-like URLs (URLs without resource name)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem and I know how to create this URL:

```
/category/drama/item/prison-break
```

Here is the question:

How can I create URLs like this?

```
/drama/prison-break
```

And is it even possible to create this:

```
/prison-break
```

Note that, I'm not asking this question for a small web app. So please avoid recommending to creating a `pages_controller`or `Page` model.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this route at the end of your `route.rb` :

`get '/:id', to: 'item#show', as: :short_item`

and then in your view use :

`short_item_path(@item)`